# Drawing a figure on MATLAB using for looping

Tags: matlab, for-loop

[image]

The code that I wrote is :

```
figure
hold on
axis equal
axis([0 20 0 10])
for k = 1:9
   plot([k(k+1)  k(k+2)],[9 1])
end
```

What I tried doing is indexing but I am not sure if this is valid in for loops.
I need help in xdata of the plot such that in first iteration the coordinates will be [k  k+1] then in 2nd iteration, the coordinates will be [k+1  k+2], 3rd would be [k+2  k+3] and so on.

Comment: If you are plotting on top of each other, you should put `hold on` after your `plot([k(k+1)  k(k+2)],[9 1])` line inside for loop. Then it creates an overlay on the same plot window.

Comment: maybe `[k+k-1  k+k]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
figure
for k=1:9
    plot([2*k-1 2*k],[9 1])
    hold on
end
axis([0 20 0 10])
axis equal
```